# Source of XSS in Javascript

Tags: javascript, eval, xss, innerhtml

I've been reading the OWASP XSS Prevention Cheat Sheet and I want to clarify my understanding. It appears to me that I am safe from this attack as long as I avoid

1. Outputting untrusted data as raw HTML (because HTML can have inline scripts).
2. Running untrusted data in eval() or New Function().
3. Allowing untrusted data in URL that can lead to scripts.
4. Using untested libraries.

The only library I am using is Raphael. If I avoid using .innerHTML .html, document.write, eval() and make sure to hard code urls will I be safe from an XSS attack? Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Btw, not planning to just blindly avoid these things, just want to be aware of where the risks are.

Comment: The raw HTML thing has nothing to do with `innerHTML` since `innerHTML` cannot be used to eval scripts. It has to do with your backend programming language (php/node/ruby/java/c# etc.). For example, how do you let users insert comments? You generate HTML from the comment stored in the database of course. Then consider your user can always write a script tag as comment

Comment: Also for example , If you have a search feature , and supposed you want to display something similar to `Search Results for : xyz` when `xyz` is the search word entered by the user , you should protect it as the user might inject a script in it .

Comment: @slebetman Ok. So if I understand you correctly innerHTML is safe and the thing to watch out for is getting raw HTML from the server. (Using php.)  I am currently sending all data from the server to the client as a json string. Is there any pitfalls I should be aware of using this method?

Comment: innerHTML is not safe. It can contain tags with event handlers which can run scripts.